# Rick and Morty API - Traer múltiples personajes

Tags: javascript, html, api, fetch

Quiero que los usuarios busquen el personaje que quieran ubicándolo por el ID, pero el problema está a la hora de seleccionar múltiples ID.

Sólo me renderiza con los parámetros /characters/1/ que es el exclusivo de "Single character".

```
const button = document.querySelector('.button');
const breakingbadContainer = document.querySelector('.image-container');


button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault;
  getData(input.value)
  console.log(getData)
}) 

function getData () {
  fetch('https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/1/')
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    createCharacter(data)
  })
}

function createCharacter (character) {
  const img = document.createElement('img')
  img.src = character.image

  const h3 = document.createElement('h3')
  h3.textContent = character.name

  const div = document.createElement('div')
  div.appendChild(img)
  div.appendChild(h3)

  breakingbadContainer.appendChild(div)

}

getData();
```

Ese es el código *javascript* que tengo y el problema está en la petición debido a que me marca 400 de una vez.

Comment: Según la documentación debes enviar en un array `/character/[1,2,3]` https://rickandmortyapi.com/documentation/

Comment: @alejandro00 es mejor pedir en un comentario aclaraciones sobre el codigo, no añadas cosas que no sabes como vienen

Answer (score 1):

Hay un par de cosas a tener en cuenta:

En primer lugar cuando se hace la peticion se llama a "character/1/" por lo que segun la documentacion https://rickandmortyapi.com/documentation/#character devolvera siempre a Rick (id = 1). En caso de requerir varios personajes se deben pasar las ID separadas con "," de la siguiente manera character/1,2,3/

```
fetch('https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/1,2,3/')
```

Lo segundo a tener en cuenta es que el request de varios personas devuelve un array de objetos y la funcion createCharacter trabaja con objetos individuales.

Y lo tercero es aca

```
button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault;
  getData(input.value)
  console.log(getData)
})
```

El console.log va a devolver la funcion pero no su resultado (porque no se la invoca y ademas ejecuta un fetch), en caso de querer ver la data se deberia hacer un console.log(data) dentro del fetch así

```
function getData () {
  fetch('https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/1/')
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data)
    createCharacter(data)
  })
}
```

Además en la invocación de getData(input.value) se envia el valor requerido para la peticion pero la funcion aun no lo implementa.

Espero haber podido guiar un poco, saludos!

Comment: se puede usar spreads operators en esa función? Me refiero, para desplegar el arreglo.

Comment: Si se puede usar spreads operators. Puede modificarse la funcion createCharacter para trabajar con arguments y llamarla como `createCharacter(...data);` De esa forma trabajaria tanto con llamadas a individuales como multiples. (Tambien puede solamente usarse un for en la llamada y no modificar la funcion) `for (let i = 0 ; i < data.length ; i++)(createCharacter(data[i])); `